# Preg replace special characters

Tags: php, regex

Hi I want to delete this character: `|` with php preg replace.
My code do not work

```
$rstr = '|||is';
$Grab->text = preg_replace($rstr,'',$Grab->text);
echo $Grab->text;
```

Comment: Why not use `str_replace("|", "", $Grab->text);`?

Comment: "do not work" how? Error message? Does nothing?

Comment: I have a lot `$rstr` to parse. I do not `str_replace("|", "", $Grab->text);` because it does not work on my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`|` is a regex meta-character, and you also use it as the delimiter (and that's 2 problems).
You should escape the `|` sign, and use another delimiter (you also don't need the `i` and `s` flags):

```
$rstr = '~\|~';
```

Your regex was interpeted as `~~|is`, and had the following error message:

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '|' in /home/o3oYmU/prog.php on line 3
```

Comment: @User - actually, that is far from perfect `:)` - try the `str_replace` function if that is applicable.

Answer (score 3):

If you really waht to use a regular expression, you need to escape the `|` character, which as a [special meaning](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php) :

```
$Grab->text = preg_replace('#\|#is', '', $Grab->text);
```

This is supposing you only want to replace one `|`, and not three in a row -- in which case you'd use :

```
$Grab->text = preg_replace('#\|{3}#is', '', $Grab->text);
```

Also note that I used `#` as [delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) -- it's easier to write/read the regex when delimiters are not characters that are present inside the regex : less escaping to do.

But, as **@Pekka** noted in his comment to your question, why not just use [**`str_replace()`**](http://www.php.net/str_replace) ?

```
$Grab->text = str_replace('|', '', $Grab->text);
```

Or, if you only want the replacement to be made when there are three `|` :

```
$Grab->text = str_replace('|||', '', $Grab->text);
```

After all, in a simple case such as this one, there is no need for regular expressions.

Comment: +1 - I'm not sure what the OP is trying to do, but this saves me a lot of typing. I've added an explanation of how `|||is` is interpreted. (oh, and now I got the accepted answer. Phoi.)

Answer (score 0):

`|` has special meaning in a regex, it is used for alternation (ie `a|b|c` means a or b or c) so you have to escape it :

```
$Grab->text = preg_replace("/\|\|\|is/",'',$Grab->text);
```

or double escape if you assing a string `$rstr = '\\|\\|\\|is';`